# R: Elements of a list into corresponding dataframe rows

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a large list that contains 5667 elements. These are the 3 last results:

```
[[997]]
 [1] 66 84 82 65 78 83 80 79 82 84 69 83 32 89 32 77 79 86 73 77 73 69 78 84 79 83 32 77 69 78 68 79 90 65 44 32 83 46 76 46

[[998]]
 [1] 66 85 71 65 83 32 65 85 84 79 77 79 67 73 79 78

[[999]]
 [1] 66 85 71 65 83 32 89 32 86 73 68 65 76

[[1000]]
 [1]  66  85  71  65  83  32  89  32  86  73  68  65  76  32  45  32 108  97  32  99 111 114 117 241  97  32  45  32  65  32  67  79  82  85 209  65

 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 4667 entries ]
```

Also I have a df with 5667 rows. I want to put each element of my list into the corresponding row of a new variable in my df.

Like:

```
df$new_variable[997] = 66 84 82 65 78 83 80 79 82 84 69 83 32 89 32 77 79 86 73 77 73 69 78 84 79 83 32 77 69 78 68 79 90 65 44 32 83 46 76 46
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create a `list` column by simply assigning the `list` to a column name

```
df$new_variable <- lst1
```

Comment: OMG! I'm feeling very stupid right now! I was overthinking the problem during several hours! ;(

Anycase is still a list:
 `> str(df$new_variable)
List of 5667
 $ : int [1:15] 65 32 86 65 82 65 32 68 69 32 ...`

How can I do to extract only the numbers as a value? Like this
`df$new_variable[997] = 66 84 82 65 78 83 80 79 82 84 69 83 32 89 32 77 79 86 73 77 73 69 78 84 79 83 32 77 69 78 68 79 90 65 44 32 83 46 76 46`

Comment: @kikusanchez  It is a `list`.  If you want as a string, then you can paste it , i.e. `df$new_variable  <- sapply(lst1, toString)`

Comment: Great! Thanks @akrun